# Center align three or more font awesome icons in the same row

Tags: html, css, less

I would usually use `margin: auto;`, `text-align: center;`, or `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to center align an icon.  But I cannot figure out how to center align three icons.  I figured using these strategies on a wrapping div would work but it hasn't.  I need them all in the same row like this:

[image]

```
<div class="socialWrap">
   <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
   <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
   <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

used `flexbox` to achieve it.

```css
.socialWrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.socialWrap a {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="socialWrap">

  <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
  <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
  <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.socialWrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="socialWrap">
  <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
  <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
  <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Display:grid` as well check snippet.

```css
.socialWrap {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="socialWrap">
  <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
  <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
  <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If You are Using Bootstrap-4 you just need to add one class only. Try this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="socialWrap text-center">
   <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
   <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
   <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="socialWrap">

  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="socialWrap" align="center">
   <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
   <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
   <a href="/content/campaigns/we-retail" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
```